# Add "active" class to bootstrap dropdown menu when dropdown link selected (with Ember link-to)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm using *Twitter Bootstrap* and have a `navbar` with a regular link and a dropdown link. Using ember's `link-to` helper, the regular link automatically gets the "active" class when clicked, as do the menu items in the dropdown menu. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out what the best way to get the parent `li` tag to get the "active" class when one of the dropdown menu items is selected. I've tried creating a component out of the dropdown menu but I cannot get it to work.

Markup in [.emblem](http://emblemjs.com/):

```
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-static-top
  ul.nav.navbar-nav

    //---------//
    // Account //
    //---------//

    link-to 'admin.business.index' tagName="li" href=false
      a href="#" Account

    //----------//
    // Branding //
    //----------//

    li.dropdown
      a.dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"
        ' Branding
        span.caret
      ul.dropdown-menu role="menu"
        link-to 'admin.business.design' tagName='li' href=false
          a href="#" Design
        link-to 'admin.business.email' tagName='li' href=false
          a href="#" Email Templates
        link-to 'admin.business.url' tagName='li' href=false
          a href="#" Vanity URL
```

I thought maybe I could nest the link-tos by replacing the "Branding" wrapper

```
li.dropdown
```

with

```
link-to 'admin.business.design' tagName='li' href=false class="dropdown"
```

but that makes the entire dropdown element a link to "admin.business.design".

**I've created a bin here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cosute/2/edit?html,output.**

You can see that "Account" and "Thing" are active when the route is, and the submenu items under "Branding" are as well, but I need "Branding" to be selected when a dropdown item under it is as well.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wacivisenori/1/edit)

This is the solution I used. Instead of making `{{link-to}}` be a `li`, make a component that is a `li`. This component makes use of the work Ember does in setting the active class for any `link-to` to the current route:

```
App.NavItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    classNameBindings: ['active'],

    active: function(){
        return this.get('childViews').isAny('active');
    }.property('childViews.@each.active')
});
```

This works because we are observing all of the `link-to` `active` properties which are set by ember with the parameter passed into the `property()`. The active property is recomputed for all `link-to` helpers each time a route changes.

Comment: works! nice, initially tried to use a component, but wasn't sure the best way to observe changes. 'childViews.@each.active' solves this.

Comment: FYI this no longer works in 1.13+  See: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11244