# Setting "active" state on Twitter Bootstrap dropdown in Ember with "each" helper rendering dropdown items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

Using Twitter Bootstrap and Ember, I'm trying to set the "active" state on the dropdown when a child item is selected, when that child was rendered using an "each" loop.

e.g.:

Snippet of my navbar in emblem:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
  link-li
    link-to 'index' | Home
  link-li classNames='dropdown'
    a.dropdown-toggle href='#' data-toggle='dropdown' Items <span class='caret'></span>
    ul.dropdown-menu
      each item in items
        link-li
          link-to 'item' item
            = item.name
      link-li
        link-to 'items.new' | Create New...
```

link-li helper from [Add "active" class to bootstrap dropdown menu when dropdown link selected (with Ember link-to)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242986/add-active-class-to-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-when-dropdown-link-selected-with)

```js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  classNameBindings: ['active'],

  active: function(){
    return this.get('childViews').isAny('active');
  }.property('childViews.@each.active')
});
```

This works great in these cases:

- Home is highlighted when on the `index` route
- Each item is highlighted when on each `item` route
- The Create New link is highlighted when on the `items.new` route
- The dropdown itself is highlighted when on the `items.new` route

But, the dropdown *does not* get highlighted when on each of the individual `item` routes.

I've investigated as far as finding out that `this.get('childViews')` only returns the one "Create New" view, seemingly ignoring the other items.  It appears to be related to the `each` helper, because any additional regular links added under "Create New" will work just fine.  And that's where my n00b Ember knowledge ends.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution to this, but it's a bit hacky...

Given a set of routes like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('items', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
  this.resource('item', {path: '/items/:item_id'}, function() {
    this.route('edit');
  });
});
```

I can get all relevant nav links to highlight by adding in hidden "dummy" links using the `link-li` helper from the question.

Navbar snippet in emblem:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
  link-li
    link-to 'index' | Home
  link-li classNames='dropdown'
    a.dropdown-toggle href='#' data-toggle='dropdown' Items <span class='caret'></span>
    ul.dropdown-menu
      span.hidden
        link-to 'items' | Items
        link-to 'item' | Item
      each item in items
        link-li
          link-to 'item' item
            = item.name
      link-li
        link-to 'items.new' | Create New...
```

By adding in the `link-to 'items'` and `link-to 'item'` dummy links, it makes the parent `link-li` helper work and properly highlight the dropdown when any of the child routes are active.

If anyone comes up with a more elegant solution, please by all means, post it here!